# What are the eigenvectors of a $3×3$ real symmetric matrix that admits $(1, 2, 3)^T$ and $(1, 1,−1)^T$ as eigenvectors.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, symmetric-matrices

A $3×3$ real symmetric matrix $M$ admits $(1, 2, 3)^T$ and $(1, 1,−1)^T$ as eigenvectors. Which of the following(s) is/are **surely** an eigenvector of $M$?

- (a) $(1,−1, 0)^T$
- (b) $(−5, 1, 1)^T$
- (c) $(3, 2, 1)^T$
- (d) None

Answer: (d)
I have tried to solve it. I know eigenvectors of a real symmetric matrix corresponding to different eigenvalues are orthogonal to each other. (But it's not true in general if we take two eigenvectors corresponding to the same eigenvalue). ($1$)
Now notice that the vectors given in the questions are orthogonal to each other. But none of (a), (b), (c) is orthogonal to both of the given vectors. ($2$)
My claim is vectors in options (a), (b) and (c) may not be an eigenvector of a symmetric matrix having eigenvectors as given in the question. So, I want to construct a real symmetric matrix having two eigenvectors $(1, 2, 3)^T$ and $(1, 1,−1)^T$ but not having $(1,−1, 0)^T$ (or, $(−5, 1, 1)^T$ or $(3, 2, 1)^T$) as eigenvector using the facts ($1$)and ($2$). 
But how to construct such matrices? Can I get any method of constructing such real symmetric matrices? Or is there any other argument to answer it in short? Thanks for the assistance in advance.

Comment: Pick a third eigenvector that’s orthogonal to the two given ones and choose three distinct eigenvalues to go with them.

Comment: @amd Yes, I have also thought like this but how to construct such symmetric matrix.

Comment: I have tried as follows. Choose a vector orthogonal to given two vectors. Now, these three vectors form a basis. The let us define a linear transformation whose matrix representation with respect to that basis is diag(d1,d2,d3) where d1, d2, d3 are distinct eigenvalues corresponding to the basis elements. Now take the matrix representation with respect to the standard basis, but that matrix may not be symmetric.

Comment: You can always normalize the eigenvectors so that the change-of-basis matrix is orthogonal.